# error: not found: value inputJPG in Scala

Tags: scala

I assigned the variable already, but I still get the error. I think that is not a typo.

```
 val inputJPG = input.filter(context => context.contains("jpg")).collect
    inputJPG.take(10)
------------------------------------------------------
    scala>  inputJPG.take(10)
    <console>:20: error: not found: value inputJPG
               inputJPG.take(10)
```

Comment: Are you using Scala collections or Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove collect. (except you have a reason that is not clear by your question)

```
val input = Seq("none","image.jpg")
val inputJPG = input.filter(context => context.contains("jpg"))
inputJPG.take(10) // -> List(image.jpg)
```

`collect` is used when you want to filter and map in one step. See the [API](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html)